# Azure VM with only private ip that can surf internet?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, ip-address

In my past experience, VM with only private ip (no public ip) cannot surf internet.

but today i create VM with only private ip.

i run this command for check
"Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://google.com -UseBasicParsing"

the result status code is 200 OK

i check this symptom more. i create vm with public ip, remote to private-vm throught public-vm and try to surf internet. it can surf.

Why is that?

private vm setting:
private ip-->10.0.2.5

public vm setting:
private ip-->10.0.2.4
public ip-->52.163.227.73

[Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL89C.png)

[ip on public vm and private vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFkFp.png)

[private vm description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pt4N.png)

[run invoke-webrequest in private vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77xZD.png)

[public vm description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Yir.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/networking-overview),

> All resources in a VNet can communicate outbound to the internet, by
> default.

If you don't want internet access, you need to adjust your security policies.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Do you know when vnet policy change?

Comment: This has not changed, Azure VM's have always have outbound internet access by default